# LogisticSigmoid residue bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

On version 10.0 for arm:

```
  Residue[LogisticSigmoid[z],{z,I Pi}]
```

gives `0` not 1.

Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: As noted in its tag wiki, please do not give questions the [tag:bugs] tag until your results have been community-vetted as an actual bug.

Comment: Anyway, for diagnostics: what happens if you feed `Residue[]` the result of `FunctionExpand[LogisticSigmoid[z]]`?

Comment: I get 1, which is correct.

Comment: Can confirm in 10.1, `Residue[LogisticSigmoid[z],{z,I Pi}]`  gives 0  while `Residue[FunctionExpand[LogisticSigmoid[z]], {z, I Pi}]` gives 1. What's going on?

Comment: Reported as a bug internally. Thanks!

Comment: `Residue` probably doesn't have a special rule for `LogisticSigmoid` and is treating it as analytic at 2 pi i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now fixed in version 10.2.

```
In[1]:= Residue[LogisticSigmoid[z], {z, I Pi}]                                  

Out[1]= 1

In[2]:= Residue[1/(1 + Exp[-z]), {z, I Pi}]                                     

Out[2]= 1

In[3]:= Coefficient[Series[1/(1 + Exp[-z]), {z, I Pi, 0}], 1/(z - I Pi)]        

Out[3]= 1
```

Comment: ilian, if I haven't already done so: thanks for all the work you and your team put into this program we all like. :)

Comment: @J. M. Thank you very much for the kind words!